# schemamigration causesTypeError for MaxValueValidator in IntegerField in django

Tags: python, django, django-south, typeerror

I am trying `schemamigration` with south on my model
(I am using `django 1.4 and python 2.6 on ubuntu`)

Initially my model was

```
class Review(models.Model):
    reviewdate=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    description=models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
```

I added a field

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator,MaxValueValidator

class Review(models.Model):
    reviewdate=models.DateField(default=date.today)
    description=models.TextField()
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(10),default=5,help_text='integers 1 to 10')
```

when I run

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
```

I get this `TypeError`

```
...
File "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/db/models/base.py", line 198, in __new__
    new_class._prepare()
  File "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/db/models/base.py", line 255, in _prepare
    cls.__doc__ = "%s(%s)" % (cls.__name__, ", ".join([f.attname for f in opts.fields]))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    sequence item 6: expected string, MaxValueValidator found
```

Can someone please tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. You should provide the validators as a list to the `validators` argument:

```
models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(10)], default=5, help_text='integers 1 to 10')
```

For more information, see the docs for [using validation in practice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#using-validation-in-practice).